# Split data in a cell to new columns Openoffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am using OpenOffice Calc.  I'm taking a data value from another sheet that is formatted like :

```
value1,value2
```

In a cell.  I need to split that into 2 cells

```
value1              value2
```

I can do it with Data->Text to Columns, but I need it to be done automatically when importing it from the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A formula to get `value1`:

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND(",";A1)-1)
```

And `value2`:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1))
```

This assumes that there are no other commas.